# How to pass value to a method in Csharp Wpf Application from XAMLl view?

Tags: wpf, xaml, methods, parameters

I have a function(Method) in my C# WPF application. I want to use this Method from several image controls.

WPF CODE

```
 <Image x:Name="cardMPOne" HorizontalAlignment="Center" MouseDown="moveCard"  Height="220" Margin="-300,20,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"  Width="100"/>
```

C SHARP

```
private void moveCard(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {

        ThicknessAnimation move = new ThicknessAnimation();
        move.From = new Thickness(sender.Margin.Left, sender.Margin.Top, 0, 0);
        move.To = new Thickness(250, 250, 0, 0);
        move.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.25));
        sender.BeginAnimation(MarginProperty, move);

    }
```

I want this method work for every image that gets hit and calls it.

I tried this also

```
    private void moveCard(Image sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e){

        ThicknessAnimation move = new ThicknessAnimation();
        move.From = new Thickness(sender.Margin.Left, sender.Margin.Top, 0, 0);
        move.To = new Thickness(250, 250, 0, 0);
        move.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.25));
        sender.BeginAnimation(MarginProperty, move);

    }
```

No errors are shown in normal. But when run. No overloads error is shown.
But when I used MouseDown="moveCard(cardMPOne)" XAML view shows error.
Confusing What to do. Anyone's Help is appreciated.. Thanks in Advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can not provide arguments like this from xaml. Instead update your handler as:

```
private void moveCard(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {

        Image image = sender as Image;
        if(image ! =null)
        {
          ThicknessAnimation move = new ThicknessAnimation();
          move.From = new Thickness(image.Margin.Left, image.Margin.Top, 0, 0);
          move.To = new Thickness(250, 250, 0, 0);
          move.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.25));
          image .BeginAnimation(MarginProperty, move);

       }
     }
```